# Is there any way to inject a service into custom decorator (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, decorator

I want to create a custom class decorator which needs an access to ChangeDetectorRef of class it was applied even if the ChangeDetectorRef isn't injected into target class.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
function ClassDecorator() {
        return (target) => {
        const changeDetectorRef = // Inject change detector ref for target;
    };
}
```

I expect to get link on an instance of ChangeDetectorRef inside my decorator. But I have no idea if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are a form of meta-programming available in TypeScript, and the docs on [class decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) state that the constructor is the only argument passed to them, so you could in theory pass an Angular injected dependency to a decorator when the class is constructed.

I think you would have to inject the ChangeDetectorRef in the decorated class every time, doubt there's a way of having the decorator dynamically inject it.